# TextToSpeech setSpeechRate not working/changing

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I am setting TextToSpeech.setSpeechRate() and it is returning TextToSpeech.SUCCESS but the speed is not changing.

It works just fine on a Galaxy Nexus running ICS, but does not work on a Thunderbolt running Gingerbread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered that the Thunderbolt has a global setting to "Always use my settings" which overrides any changes to TextToSpeech by apps.

It is in the device's settings, then in "Voice input & output" and then, "Text-to-speech settings".

You can check this by calling [textToSpeech.areDefaultsEnforced()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#areDefaultsEnforced%28%29)

The reason this worked fine in ICS was because:

> As of the Ice cream sandwich release, user settings never forcibly override the app's settings.